# Import WeakMethod error in Django 1.9 with python 3.3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I'm using django 1.9.1 with python 3.3.
Getting following error when I'm running runserver

```
File "/home/virtualenv/python3.3.5/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/dispatch/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import Signal, receiver # NOQA
File "/home/virtualenv/python3.3.5/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 14, in <module>
from weakref import WeakMethod
ImportError: cannot import name WeakMethod
```

As I was reading WeakMethod of weakref has been introduced in python 3.4, and its not exist in weakref of python 3.3.

Any suggestions on how to fix the same error with python 3.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django 1.9.x does not support Python 3.3:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django

> Typically, we will support a Python version up to and including the
>   first Django LTS release whose security support ends after security
>   support for that version of Python ends. For example, Python 3.3
>   security support ends September 2017 and Django 1.8 LTS security
>   support ends April 2018. **Therefore Django 1.8 is the last version to
>   support Python 3.3.**

You can either downgrade to Django 1.8 or upgrade your Python interpreter to 3.4 or higher.